# How can you stop resending a webpage when the client doesen't return an answer to the server

Tags: ddos, client-side-attacks

I want to host a web server, but there's something in my way: DDoS attacks. I'm very new to hosting a web server, and i just recently found out about them. I might be wrong, but I know that when bots send requests to the server, they do not return an answer to the server, so the server tries to send the file that the bot wants again and again. Is there a way to make a server return the file 5 times if the client "doesent get" the file, and the 6th time the server doesent return the file to that client again?

I apologize if the question or the title is a bit confusing, my english is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a hosting solution such as CloudFlare:

> Cloudflare, Inc. is a U.S. company that provides a content delivery
>   network, Internet security services and distributed domain name server
>   services, sitting between the visitor and the Cloudflare user's
>   hosting provider, acting as a reverse proxy for websites.
>  Cloudflare
>   is headquartered in San Francisco, California, with additional offices
>   in London, Singapore, Champaign, Austin, Boston and Washington, D.C...

Comment: Next time ill research more. Thanks!